# How to run database class methods inside other classes?

Tags: php, class

I am new to using classes in PHP, I just realized, in most of my class methods, I need to do some mysql queries.  I have another class that handles my connection and queries but how should I go about calling that class from other classes?  Doesn't this kind of defeat the purpose of using classes if all my classes rely on my DB class?

Comment: Some sample code would help to illustrate what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is usually solved with the Singleton or Factory pattern...

when you need to use the db, you snatch the app's db object:

```
$db = Site::getDb();   // singleton
$db->exec('update t set i = i + 1');
```

getDb returns a static instance.

or:

```
 $db = Db::getDb('dsn');   // factory
 $db->exec('update t set i = i + 1');
```

returns a static instance if it exists, or creates a new db handle for that dsn...

Comment: +1, Nice answer, but don't you mean `Db::getDb()` instead of `Site::getDb()`?

Comment: sorry I am still learning this stuff, as I understand it, a singlton is used for the connection part, if as connection was already called/made then it uses that connection otherwise it creates a new one right?  SO my main question here is based on what I have so far, I have a sessions class which sets and gets session variables for me instead of using the default set and get session features of PHP, I wrapped them in a class so I can change to use any kind of cache system down the road.  I also have a database class which will make the connection and have methods for making queries.  The way I

Comment: see it is that I will need to have access to the database and session classes in all my other classes, I am just wanting to know if this is normal or not?  Like let's say I decide to build a different site, if I try to use a "forums" class it will not work unless I bring over my database and session classes as well.  I think this is OK but I am a total newbie with classes and such